# Is there a CSS only way to compress a page layout with a slide and push menu, without it going off the side?

Tags: html, css, menu

I am doing a slide and push menu but I would like the page to compress, as in not getting pushed off the side so part of the page isn't visible, but just changing its width.. 'squishing' it, so that the layout  resizes to fit and nothing gets cut off.

My idea is to have a page and a dashboard type slide out menu that you can choose to have open while on the page or not. So all the page content must be visible when the slide out menu is open or closed.

Thanks in advance for any help you could give!

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2u64k0xq/1/

HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>

<div class="site-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi vero nisi eos sed qui natus, ut eius reprehenderit error nesciunt veniam aliquam nulla itaque labore obcaecati molestiae eveniet, perferendis provident amet perspiciatis expedita accusantium! Eveniet, quos voluptas et, labore natus, saepe unde est nulla sit eaque tempore debitis accusantium. Recusandae.</p>
    <p>Dolorem aliquam a libero reiciendis obcaecati doloribus ipsa eos laudantium, dicta in! Odit iure ut ratione, dolorum cupiditate perferendis voluptatum sapiente, dignissimos sunt necessitatibus, reprehenderit consequatur dolorem. Aliquam veniam quaerat, pariatur deserunt reiciendis vero vitae, repellat omnis sequi dolor nesciunt. Nihil similique alias impedit, obcaecati eligendi delectus voluptatum! Ipsum, vel.</p>
    <p>Sint, perspiciatis nemo aut, rerum excepturi deleniti modi quos nihil corporis eum, maiores soluta labore, consectetur eligendi nesciunt. Placeat, incidunt! Illum placeat eligendi, veritatis consectetur eum! Dolor obcaecati minima ab placeat voluptatem neque modi doloribus, magnam qui voluptate eaque in. Nulla expedita hic porro architecto facere officiis vitae numquam, dolor!</p>
    <p>Perferendis quis ea incidunt ducimus nisi voluptate natus. Repellat asperiores quod rerum rem quos blanditiis enim modi, veniam voluptas a facilis! Velit cum omnis, voluptatum eum inventore! Corrupti, suscipit, neque distinctio expedita est laboriosam cum aliquid minus tempora quaerat officia possimus unde vel deleniti eaque fugit accusamus iusto dolorum natus.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Navigation Menu - Background */

.navigation {
  /* critical sizing and position styles */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;

  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  list-style: none;
  background: #111;
}

/* Navigation Menu - List items */
.nav-item {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid #111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav-item a {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  color: #c74438;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(75,20,20,0.65) 100%);
}

/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
.site-wrap {
  /* Critical position and size styles */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: white; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  padding: 4em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(254,255,255) 0%,rgb(221,241,249) 35%,rgb(160,216,239) 100%);
  background-size: 200%;
}

/* Nav Trigger */
.nav-trigger {
  /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  position: fixed;
  left: 15px; top: 15px;
  z-index: 2;

  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
  background-size: contain;
}

/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
  transition: left 0.2s;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
  left: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

body {
    /* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Micro reset */
*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vothaison

there's no need to use `left` property, OP can easily achieve this as:

```
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  min-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

And also instead on collapsing event you should add `transition` form the very start for both of the classes:

```
label[for="nav-trigger"], .site-wrap {
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

### Code Snippet

```css
/* Navigation Menu - Background */

.navigation {
  /* critical sizing and position styles */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  list-style: none;
  background: #111;
}
/* Navigation Menu - List items */

.nav-item {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid #111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.nav-item a {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}
.nav-item a:hover {
  color: #c74438;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(75, 20, 20, 0.65) 100%);
}
/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */

.site-wrap {
  /* Critical position and size styles */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  padding: 4em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(254, 255, 255) 0%, rgb(221, 241, 249) 35%, rgb(160, 216, 239) 100%);
  background-size: 200%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
/* Nav Trigger */

.nav-trigger {
  /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  position: fixed;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
  background-size: contain;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
/* Make the Magic Happen */

.nav-trigger + label,
.site-wrap {} .nav-trigger:checked + label {
  left: 215px;
}
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  min-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
body {
  /* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* Micro reset */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>

<div class="site-wrap">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi vero nisi eos sed qui natus, ut eius reprehenderit error nesciunt veniam aliquam nulla itaque labore obcaecati molestiae eveniet, perferendis provident amet perspiciatis expedita accusantium!
    Eveniet, quos voluptas et, labore natus, saepe unde est nulla sit eaque tempore debitis accusantium. Recusandae.</p>
  <p>Dolorem aliquam a libero reiciendis obcaecati doloribus ipsa eos laudantium, dicta in! Odit iure ut ratione, dolorum cupiditate perferendis voluptatum sapiente, dignissimos sunt necessitatibus, reprehenderit consequatur dolorem. Aliquam veniam quaerat,
    pariatur deserunt reiciendis vero vitae, repellat omnis sequi dolor nesciunt. Nihil similique alias impedit, obcaecati eligendi delectus voluptatum! Ipsum, vel.</p>
  <p>Sint, perspiciatis nemo aut, rerum excepturi deleniti modi quos nihil corporis eum, maiores soluta labore, consectetur eligendi nesciunt. Placeat, incidunt! Illum placeat eligendi, veritatis consectetur eum! Dolor obcaecati minima ab placeat voluptatem
    neque modi doloribus, magnam qui voluptate eaque in. Nulla expedita hic porro architecto facere officiis vitae numquam, dolor!</p>
  <p>Perferendis quis ea incidunt ducimus nisi voluptate natus. Repellat asperiores quod rerum rem quos blanditiis enim modi, veniam voluptas a facilis! Velit cum omnis, voluptatum eum inventore! Corrupti, suscipit, neque distinctio expedita est laboriosam
    cum aliquid minus tempora quaerat officia possimus unde vel deleniti eaque fugit accusamus iusto dolorum natus.</p>

  <p>Demo by Austin Wulf. <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu">See article</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

My thought, first, remove *min-width: 100%* from .site-wrap

Then, add *width: calc(100% - 200px);* (hope you are writing code for new browsers).

```
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

Add a bit more transition so that .site-wrap moves to the right and resizes simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!